# JavaScript: Why doesn't the background change to the user's selection (simple)?

Tags: javascript, forms

I have two radio buttons, one for the colour red and one for the colour blue. The user selects one and the selected colour appears as the background colour. That's what I want, and I've managed to get this to work when it comes to changing an image but for some reason my code doesn't work.

When I select red, nothing happens, then I select blue and the page turns red. I must be doing something really stupid wrong.

JS:

```
function getColour() {
    var rad = document.forms["Form2"]["ColourRad"];
    var i, x;

    for (i = 0; i < rad.length; i++) {
        if (rad[i].checked) {
            x = rad[i].value
        }
    }
    changeColour(x);

}

function changeColour(colour) {

    if (colour == "Blue") {
        document.body.style.backround = "Blue"
    } else if (colour == "Red") {
        document.body.style.background = "Red"
    }

}
```

HTML:

```
<body>
   <form name="Form2">Do you prefer the colour red or blue?
       <input type="radio" name="ColourRad" onchange="getColour()" value="Blue" />Red
       <input type="radio" name="ColourRad" onchange="getColour()" value="Red" />Blue
    </form>
</body>
```

JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rwowf5j8/29/

Comment: Your inputs have the wrong values, blue has a value of red and vice versa.  Also you have a typo in `changeColour` - the first `if` block says `backround`.  [Here's a fixed fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rwowf5j8/34/)

Comment: AHAHA how stupid of me, long day, stop noticing the little things

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using your function to change the background color:

```js
   function getColour() {
       var rad = document.forms["Form2"]["ColourRad"];
       var i, x;

       for (i = 0; i < rad.length; i++) {
           if (rad[i].checked) {
               x = rad[i].value
           }
       }
       changeColour(x);

   }

   function changeColour(colour) {
       //if the value of the input is the color, you don't need 
       //to check if the color is blue or red to set it
       document.body.style.background = colour
   }
```

```html
<form name="Form2">Do you prefer the colour red or blue?
    <!--in your code, the Red input is with Blue color -->
    <input type="radio" name="ColourRad" onchange="getColour()" value="Red" />Red

     <!--the same with the Blue input, where the Blue is Red -->
    <input type="radio" name="ColourRad" onchange="getColour()" value="Blue" />Blue
</form>
```

Also you can use this instead:

```html
<form name="Form2">Do you prefer the colour red or blue?
    <input type="radio" name="ColourRad" onchange="document.body.style.backgroundColor = this.value" value="red" />Red
    <input type="radio" name="ColourRad" onchange="document.body.style.backgroundColor=this.value" value="blue" />Blue
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed your script on http://jsfiddle.net/rwowf5j8/41/

Fixed and tested -- Issue was in the spelling in  document.body.style.backround and there were some other tricks to do that easily so I fixed that..

```
<script>
  function getColour(value) {
 changeColour(value);
 }

function changeColour(colour) {
if (colour == "Blue") {
 document.body.style.background = "blue";
} 
else if (colour == "Red") {
 document.body.style.background = "Red";
  }
 }

 </script>

 <body>
  <form name="Form2">Do you prefer the colour red or blue?
  <input type="radio" name="ColourRad" onchange="getColour('Red')" value="Blue" />Red
 <input type="radio" name="ColourRad" onchange="getColour('Blue')" value="Red" />Blue
</form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

A Very Simple Method to do this..

Hope this helps you.

```js
document.onreadystatechange = function()
{
 if(document.readyState == "complete")
 { 
     var blue = document.getElementById("blue");
     var red  = document.getElementById("red") ;

     blue.onclick = function()
     {
  document.body.style.background = "blue";
     }

     red.onclick = function()
     {
      document.body.style.background = "red";
     }
 }
}
```

```html
<body>
   <form name="Form2">Do you prefer the colour red or blue?
<input id="red" type="radio" name="color" value="Blue" />Red
<input id="blue" type="radio" name="" value="Red" />Blue
</form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another method. First, I wait for the document to finish loading. Next, I get a list of all elements that have the name 'colorRad' - this allows me to collect a list of all the radio buttons involved in setting the background color.

Next, I attach an event listener that simply gets the value of the radio-button when its selected and finally, applies this to the background-color of the document body's inline style.

Adding a new colour option is as simple as duplicating one of the radio buttons and changing the text displayed in it's label **and** by setting it's value - this label also allows you to select a radio button with the text, as opposed to limiting the target area to the size of the radio-button's circle only.

Lastly, since the `onRadBtnChanged` function is attached to each radio-button's object, when the function is called, the `this` parameter refers to the radio-button object itself. This allows us to get info from the radio-button's value, and avoids having to handle each option specifically, as you have done in your `changeColor` function. Also, we save the wasted cpu cycles of iterating through the entire list each time, as you do in `getColor` - only one can be selected at a time - attaching the event-handler to the object itself means that we only need concern ourselves with the particular element that changed. (the change event only fires when the radio-button is selected. It does *not* fire when the selection of a different one causes one to be deselected - it only fires on selection, or 'checking')

**Example:**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
window.addEventListener('load', onDocLoaded, false);

function onDocLoaded(evt)
{
    var colRadBtns = document.getElementsByName('colorRad');
    var i, n = colRadBtns.length;
    for (i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        colRadBtns[i].addEventListener('change', onRadBtnChanged, false);
    }
}

function onRadBtnChanged(evt)
{
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = this.value;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <label><input name='colorRad' value='red' type='radio'/>Red</label>
    <label><input name='colorRad' value='blue' type='radio'/>Blue</label>

    <label><input name='colorRad' value='yellow' type='radio'/>Yellow</label>
    <label><input name='colorRad' value='green' type='radio'/>Green</label>
    <label><input name='colorRad' value='orange' type='radio'/>Orange</label>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The 2 things you needed to do were:

1. Switch the values in the input tags because they didn't match up.
2. In the changeColour() function, you didn't fully spell out background in `document.body.style.backround` you missed the g.

I also switched the script tags from the top to be at the bottom, right before the closing body tag just because I usually do it like that.

Fixing those two small issues makes it run perfectly.

Answer (score -1):

Use this instead:

```
    document.body.style.backgroundColor
```

Answer (score -1):

basically the style property was wrong, it should be **backgroundColor**
but you can get the same effect much simpler, for example:

onchange="document.body.style.backgroundColor=this.value;"

Comment: There is a [background](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background) CSS property - it works fine.